# MinGW gcc error: "undefined reference to `yylloc'"

Tags: flex-lexer

Where can I find yylloc? I have included libfl.a (-lfl) in gcc command line, added GnuWin32/bin and GnuWin32/lib directories to system variable LIB, searched through all files in GnuWin32 - neither I nor gcc can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Bison variable, it cannot be used without Bison-generated .c file.